# How to synchronize Chrome web history on different Android devices?

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser-history

In Chrome, I can find options to synchronize bookmarks, passwords, web search (nice feature) but nothing about my web history synchronization.

Am I missing an obvious option ? Is there an external application that could do that or should I try to synchronize manually my history ?

This is particulary annoying when doing a search in my desktop Chrome, looking for some results, trying one website, another... then later doing the same research on one of my Android device and re-trying the same websites and discover after loading that I already visited this site with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

## Google Chrome Application for Android

The Google Chrome Application for Android comes with some sync features as to allow users to keep their web-experience mirrored to other devices or desktop computers.

1. You need to be signed in on the services screen:

   > If you're not on the sign-in services screen, touch Menu > Settings > your email address to manage your sign-in options.
2. You can adjust your sync settings from the Services screen:

   > touch Sync to adjust your settings.
3. You can either set the sync to affect all data or specify each data is intend to be synced:

   - **Enable the service:**

     > Use the blue slider at the top of the screen to enable or disable the service.
   - **Define what's to be synced:**

     > If you don't want to sync everything, deselect the Sync everything checkbox and choose the data you'd like to sync.
   - **Encrypt your data:**

     > Touch Encryption to choose whether to use your Google Account password or a custom passphrase to protect your data.
   - **Rest the sync service:**

     > Touch Reset sync to remove synced data from your account. If you've forgotten your sync passphrase, use this option to reset the passphrase.

**Note:**

> To fully take advantage of this feature, make sure you're signed in to Chrome on other devices, such as your computer or tablet.

<sup>Additional documentation about this can be found at [Google Chrome Support page for sync data](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2392075).</sup>

---

## Google Web History

Google takes care of this for you as long as you've logged yourself into your Google Account on every browser and/or device you use.

Additionally, using [history.google.com](https://history.google.com/history/), you can manage the information stored:

[image: Google Web History Management Page]

*What I most enjoy with this is the fact that all my searches are synced between Mobile, Desktop and Laptop, saving me precious time.*

Comment: I known my search are stored and synchronized, what I want is to synchronize the site I visited, not only the one I searched.

Comment: @CédricJulien Are you referring to the color change of a link, that lets you know you've visited that site already?

Comment: yes, that's it :)

Comment: @CédricJulien Google takes care of that for you thru the web history :) *(but that only works for their sites, not inside another site!)*

Comment: @CédricJulien I'll improve the answer with the available settings provided by the Google Chrome App.

Answer (score 0):

Sign in to Chrome on your Android device. Open Chrome on your Andorid device, go to Settings and you will see "Sing in to Chrome". Select the option and sign in. After that, your Android device history appears on your Chrome desktop.